# Слово "Святой" с большой буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В сочетании с именем слово святой пишется со строчной – святой Иоанн, святая Маргарита и т. д.

А если нет имени? Например: "На фреске изображены святые и ангелы". Как написать слово "святые" в этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно используется строчная буква: **святые и ангелы.**

Это **святые угодники, святые праведники.**

Пример:

Иконостас является живою цепью божественных стражей; **ангелы и святые** не допустят в область горнего мира тех, кто не ведает премудрого страха Божия. [Б. А. Садовской. Пшеница и плевелы (1936-1941) // «Новый Мир», 1993]

**Из словаря: Святой.** 3. только полн. Религ. Проведший жизнь в служении Богу и церкви или пострадавший за христианскую веру и признанный церковью небесным покровителем верующих, как способный творить чудеса. Апостол с. Пётр. С-ые угодники, праведники. С-ые праотцы (древние, патриархи, ветхозаветные праведники.